# JPA and selective ManyToOne relationship

Tags: jpa, entity-relationship, one-to-many

Sure this is a simple answer, but I cannot find the right source to give the details.
I have a ManyToOne relationship. Because of a synchronization system, when a child is removed a field named 'removed' is set to 'true', and will automatically be deleted only a month later.

However, in the meanwhile, I would like it not to appear in the List in the parent. Is there an easy way to specify a select statement in the definition of the field or so?

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
@OrderBy("level")
public List<MenuItem> children;
```

Comment: If you are using Hibernate then look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/675979/how-to-filter-collection-in-jpa-jpql . Otherwise, if you wish to use strict JPA implementations, why don't you create a method or directly a query for the purpose?

Comment: Which JPA implementation do you use? I don't think this is supported by the standard.

Comment: I use Hibernate. Sure that could be an option, I was just wondering if there was an attribute that could be added to the declaration or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using hibernate you can use the @where annotation. I never used it myself but it seems quite straight forward. Have a look here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-collection